# How to read a particular video frame by its frame index in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am working on a algorithm which takes a single video frame by its index, processes it and takes the next video frame of the new index.

I am reading the video file using Matlab VideoReader function. To read the next frame it provide readFrame function.

The readFrame function can take time of the frame and reads that particular frame at that time. How do I use it to read a particular frame at a given index?

I am using Matlab 2016b in Linux. I have the mmread function which takes video filename and frame index to read the frame. But this file depends on a Windows 64 bit compiled Matlab function file, so I can't use it.

Here's how I am using it:

```
for i = startIdx:endIdx
    frame = mmread(filename, i);
    ...
    processing the frame
    ...
end
```

This the [link](http://www.pudn.com/Download/item/id/607168.html) to the mmread function I got from for Windows.

Comment: Please add your existing code, so we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [read](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.read.html) function. However the documentation suggests that it is not recommended (I don't know why).

```matlab
v = VideoReader(filename);

for i = startIdx:endIdx
    frame = read(v,i);
    ...
    processing the frame
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Addition to the answer by @ga97dil. As he said and Matlab suggests to not to use the [read](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.read.html) function, instead suggests to use [VideoReader.readFrame](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.readframe.html) funtion to read a frame.

Since, this function doesn't takes a frame index as an argument but a specific time to read a frame, I thought what if I can convert a specific frame index to its time in the video. After googling a bit, I found [this](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/298991-reading-in-only-specific-video-frames-with-readframe) thread as a soulution.

Here's how I defined my new mmread.m function

```
function [ frame ] = mmread_1(filename, frameIdx)
    v = VideoReader(filename);  % read the video file
    v.CurrentTime = (frameIdx - 1) / v.FrameRate;  % calculate the time for the given frame index
    frame = readFrame(v);  % read the frame
end
```

Since Matlab suggests not to use read function(may be it will be removed in future releases), I prefer not using it due to portability.